# How to write cross-browser compatible userscripts?

Tags: cross-browser, greasemonkey, userscripts

My past attempts at writing userscripts ended working in Firefox, but not Opera, because of subtle differences between the two browsers. Is it possible to use of those libraries that abstract the differences away like jQuery inside userscripts to make them cross-browser compatible with little effort?

Comment: If you mention the particular area(s) you are having trouble, we should be able to help feature test and resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as the google search for [greasemonkey jquery](http://www.google.com/search?q=greasemonkey+jquery&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a) shows:

- http://userscripts.org/topics/2324
- http://joanpiedra.com/jquery/greasemonkey/

As the posts in the first link say, it means you add a relatively large jQuery cost to your userscript. It's not very hard to make the code work across Firefox and Opera -- you don't have to worry about IE :)